# Open multiple modal with remote content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

i use to open my modals like this and works fine

```
 <a href="/my-ajax-page.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#remoteModal" class="btn btn-default">Open Modal</a>  

<!-- Modal -->  
<div class="modal fade" id="remoteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="remoteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">  
    <div class="modal-dialog">  
        <div class="modal-content"></div>  
    </div>  
</div>  
<!-- /.modal -->
```

now i m try to use different links to load the content inside my modal like

```
    <a href="/my-ajax-page.html?id=1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#remoteModal">Open Modal 1</a> 

    <a href="/my-ajax-page.html?id=2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#remoteModal">Open Modal 2</a> 

    <a href="/my-ajax-page.html?id=3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#remoteModal">Open Modal 3</a>
```

i used on my example just 3 links but the number of links can be 10, 20 etc

Answer (score 1):

I just found a answer here http://jsfiddle.net/sherbrow/thlyb/

```
$('[data-load-remote]').on('click',function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(this);
var remote = $this.data('load-remote');
if(remote) {
    $($this.data('remote-target')).load(remote);
}
});



   <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/Sherbrow/bHmRB/0/show/" data-remote-target="#myModal .modal-body">Btn 1</a>    
   <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/Sherbrow/bHmRB/1/show/" data-remote-target="#myModal .modal-body">Btn 2</a>
   <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/Sherbrow/bHmRB/2/show/" data-remote-target="#myModal .modal-body">Btn 3</a>
   <a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-load-remote="http://fiddle.jshell.net/Sherbrow/bHmRB/3/show/" data-remote-target="#myModal .modal-body">Btn 4</a>

 <div class="modal hide" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>One fine body…</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
</div>
```

thanks anyway